# Will changing Article Category in Bulk with MySQL affect the integrity of assets table?

Tags: mysql, category, permissions

I need to change the category of around 100 articles from CatA with id 1 to CatB with id 2. Both categories are created and there are 100 Menu Items that point to the Articles currently in Category A.

Since changing all of them manually will take a lot more than a simple MySQL query to update the com_content table; I was thinking of doing it but my concern is whether this will affect the integrity of assets table in any way. The permission level of CatA and CatB are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will.

Instead go to:

Joomla! Administrator
-> Content
-> Articles

Click the tick box to tick all article.

Then click 'Batch' up the top.

Under:

> To Move or Copy your selection please select a Category.

Select your new category, make sure 'Move' is selected and then click Process.

This will do it all for you and update the relevant category and assets table/row.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I knew about that method but when you have over 100 articles and no common way to search I was thinking maybe a MySQL query could do it but no way I am doing it now as the last thing I would want is to mess up the assets table after having had some bad experiences with it.

Comment: You are very welcome, if in doubt you can view the query by enabling Joomla! debug mode. Change the article of a category for instance and you will see the changes to the assets table as per each category. 

Can you filter out the results and then run a batch? For example, If you want to move articles from Cat1 to Cat2 then click 'Search Tools' in the articles view. Then select category and select Cat1. You can then proceed to batch that category again.

Comment: Yes could do that but currently the 100 articles is across multiple categories and it is actually part of over 1000 articles so I guess it will be a bit of a manual task this one. And yes turning on the debug mode to check how it affects the assets tables makes sense.